# Content-Security-Policy via spring security is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, content-security-policy

Today I tried to implement Content-Security-Policy with spring security and spring boot.
Below is the config as part of spring security.

```
        http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .headers()
        .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Content-Security-Policy","script-src none; style-src none;"))
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter(), SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(keycloakAuthenticatedActionsRequestFilter(), KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
        .logoutUrl("/sso/logout").permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/token").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/ignore/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

As per the code Content-Security-Policy attribute is being added to response as below

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DE7BF66B7B8EE56A863XXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Security-Policy: script-src none;style-src none;
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 20:46:05 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

Though policy is added to the response correctly and I have given **script-src none; style-src none;** but still the whole application loads without any issues neither any error appears.

I even tried as bellow:

`.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'none';")`
`.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self';")`

event though with multiple trials response body in the browser shows Content-Security-Policy attribute but it doesnot work as expected.

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'none'` token should be single quoted, you should have errors in the browser console about that. Try `addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Content-Security-Policy","script-src 'none'; style-src 'none';"))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @granty, I tried it but even adding 'none' didnot work.

Comment: "did not work" is not a technical description of what's goin on. Much better to say do you see single quoted `'none'` in the response header or not. In case of presense  `"Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'none';style-src 'none';"` it cannot but work. Only if some browser extension cuts out CSP header.

Comment: Yes, I see "Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'none';style-src 'none';" in the response header but still all the content of the application loads which is not expected behavior, I tried in chrome and edge.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you send CSP header with `Content-Type: application/json` MIME type. It won't work, you already have HTML page (which parses application/json and render it) loaded into browser. You have to send CSP along with this base HTML page, not with the content subrequests.

Comment: I tried adding CSP to index.html through <meta> tag, and it started working however, <meta> doesnot support report-uri or report-only. As I am using CSP for the first time I just dont want to block the application either ways. As I am new to CSP do you suggest any solution which guide me well any resource or blog which can help me out? Thanks @granty

Comment: I am using angular as a front end, spring boot and security as a backend. Angular running on 4200 port and spring boot on 8081

Comment: Yes `<meta Content-Security-Policy>` is useles when debug CSP. But Spring boot [can publish](https://csplite.com/csp221/) CSP header. If you wish to handle CSP reports on your own, BIRT or Jasper Report can help. Above link is a best startpoint if you need a CSP's nitty-gritty. Best CSP info resource is `developer.mozilla.org` - [MDN: CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) and MDN: [CSP directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy).